# How to create an orthographic/isometric directional light with three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a shadow in my orthographic scene in three.js. I'd like to have a directional light so the shadow is offset from all objects equally in the scene. I am however having problems using `DirectionalLight`.

My first problem is that I can't get the shado to cover the entire scene, only part of it ever has a shadow. I played with the light's frustum settings, but can't figure out how to get it to cover the scene. Ideally I'd want the frustrum to match that of the camera.

[image]

The second problem is that the shadows aren't "clean". If I use a SpotLight the shadows have nice crisp borders (but obviously not the universal directionality I want). When I use a DirectionalLight the borders are misshappen and blurry.

[image]

In the samples the tile is a simply box created with CubeGeometry.

How can I create an ortographic directional light source for my scene?

Comment: 1. What light "frustum settiings" did you "play with"? 2. Experiment with `renderer.shadowMapType` and `light.shadowMapWidth/Height`.

Comment: I've changed the shadowCamera settings which alters my coverage (that is where the clipping comes from I believe). The quality is definitely related to the shadowMapWidth. I think the shadow camera is tilted, thus I have a rotated shadowMap over the field, resulting in the strange shadows. I'm not clear on how to fix it.

Comment: I am not clear what your problem is, or what your question is. Can you edit your post and provide a live example?